# Creating a dynamic object from type that is also dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic, types

I have a problem and I could really use your help.

I have a method that sends a dynamic type, and I want to create an object from that type and then set some properties. Here is the code to make it more clear:

```
private void Foo(dynamic type)
    {
        dynamic instanceOfType = Activator.CreateInstance(type); 

        //I realize that it probably doesn't make sense to create a dynamic
        //instance of something, but if I put 'object' instead of it, then
        //I can't set SomeProperty that is specific to my type

        instanceOfType.SomeProperty = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(); //ignore the right side
    }
```

I hope that my question is clear enough and that it makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use an interface?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TrySetMember method.
Learn more about it here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trysetmember(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is something like this:

```
private void Foo(dynamic objectWithTypeToClone)
{
    dynamic instanceOfType = Activator.CreateInstance(objectWithTypeToClone.GetType()); 

    instanceOfType.SomeProperty = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(); //ignore the right side
}
```